# Проверить, если в json-массиве содержится лишь одно свойство

Tags: javascript

Как можно проверить json-объект на то, присутствует ли в нём только один элемент? Специфичность API, с которым я работаю, состоит в том, что его надо опрашивать в течение 30 секунд с определённой периодичностью и он возвращает json-массив с данными. Но когда сбор данных окончен, API сигнализирует мне об этом таким образом, что отдаёт массив только с одним свойством `search_id`. Я хочу проверять каждый массив на то, содержится ли в нём только одно это свойство или помимо него ещё есть и остальные. И если там только одно это свойство - прерывать опрос API в связи с окончанием его работы. Как это сделать правильно?

Данные в нормальном виде:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

API сигнализирует об окончании сбора данных:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добавь пример ответов когда сбор окончен и когда нет

Comment: @Grundy в строковом виде массивы слишком большие. Добавлю в виде объектов.

Comment: так не надо добавлять полностью 100000 элементов, в примере достаточно одного-двух элементов в массиве. И что значит _ в строковом виде массивы слишком большие. Добавлю в виде объектов_? какой строковый вид имеется ввиду? и что за в виде объектов?

Comment: @Grundy добавил. Так, по-моему, понятнее будет.

Comment: как вариант можно брать ключи первого объекта в массиве, с помощью Object.keys, и если в полученном массиве всего один элемент - значит все

Answer (score 2):

[Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) возвращает массив всех *собственных перечислямых* ключей объекта.

```js
function test(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).length === 1 && 
    Object.keys(obj)[0] === 'search_id';
}

console.log(test({id: 5}));
console.log(test({search_id: 5}));
console.log(test([{search_id: 5}][0]));
```